# Error Failed to load PDF document. (Angular5)

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, download, blob

I am trying to get PDF document from Web API, and want to show in Angular App. Getting "Failed to load PDF document error".

Please follow my code:

My service.ts

```
public download_pdf(id: string): Observable<any> {
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
        headers.append('id', id);
        return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.download_pdf), {
          headers: headers,
          responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer,

        }).map(
          response => (<Response>response).blob())
    }
```

My component.ts

```
  downloadFile2(id) {
    this.ws.download_pdf(id).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        let mediaType = 'application/pdf';
        let blob = new Blob([response._body], {type: mediaType});
        let filename = 'test.pdf';
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
      });
  }
```

Template.html

```
  <button>
   <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"(click)="downloadFile2(item.id)"></i>
  </button>
```

> Result is: download a test.pdf --> Error Failed to load PDF document.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps to resolve the issue.

Step 1. Convert your byte array to base64 string in your API like below

```
[HttpGet("Downloadpdf/{SessionKey}")]
        public IActionResult Downloadpdf(string SessionKey)
        {
            Byte[] pdf = null;
            try
            {
                pdf = PDFService.Downloadpdf(SessionKey);//Here you need to modify and get byte array like byte[]
                string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdf);
                return Ok(pdfBase64);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

step 2. Add a below function to convert from base64 string to ArrayBuffer in .ts file

```
base64ToArrayBuffer(base64:any):ArrayBuffer {
      var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
      var len = binary_string.length;
      var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
          bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return bytes.buffer;
  }
```

step 3. Call step2 function in your custom function for button click event

```
let sessionKey: any ="sessiontoken";
      this.pdfService.downloadpdf(sessionKey).subscribe((data: any) => {
        var byteArray = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(data);
        let blob: any = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        saveAs(blob, 'Report.pdf',true);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: The changes you mentioned works well for me, but I wanted to understand why it is necessary to convert to ToBase64String instead of returning the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also in Angular 10.

##### Service.ts

```js
    getPdf():Observable<any> { 
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}Controller/GetPdf`);
      }
```

##### Component.ts

```js
    this.service.getPdf().subscribe((resp) => {
      
          let response = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(resp);
          let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          window.open(fileURL);
        
      });
     }
```

###### Helper method

```js
    base64ToArrayBuffer(base64:any):ArrayBuffer {
      var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
      var len = binary_string.length;
      var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
          bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return bytes.buffer;
    }
```